# Generic interface not behaving as expected

Tags: java, generics

I have a simple generic interface

```
public interface Person<T> {
    T foo(T other);
}
```

and a class

```
    public class Data<T extends Person> {

      public void doSomething(List<T> data){
         data.stream().reduce((a, b) -> (T)a.foo(b));
      }
  }
```

when I'm using reduce with the function `foo` that's suppose to return the generic type `T` the compiler says that it cannot be returned because it's a bad return type.

But as you can see the method `foo` gets and return `T`?

also when I'm autocompleting with my workspace `myObj.foo(obj)` 
I'm seeing that the return type and the parameter type is an object type.
anyone can explain to me why it's happening, why it not from a `T` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the generic parameter of `Person`:

```
public class Data<T extends Person<T>> {
    ...
}
```

Or move your generics a around a bit, I do not yet see what sense that generic parameter makes.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using the letter `T` to stand for two entirely different type parameters - the type parameter in the `Person` generic class and the type parameter in the `Data` generic class.

These aren't the same parameter - and you've managed to confuse yourself by using the same letter for both.  The compiler, however, is not confused; and it tells you quite correctly that you can't use one `T` in place of the other.

In particular, you've tried to cast an expression whose type is the `T` that `foo` returns, to the other type of `T`.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing 2 parameters here. `T` in

```
public interface Person<T> {
    T foo(T other);
}
```

defines a paramer on interface `Person`.

```
public class Data<T extends Person> {
    public void doSomething(List<T> data) {
        data.stream().reduce((a, b) -> (T)a.foo(b));
    }
}
```

Defines a parameter of class `Data` of type `Person` which is implicitly equal to `Person<Object>`.

So `List<T>` is list of object extending `Person` and method `foo()` has return type of Person first parameter `Object` while `reduce` expects the return type be of type `Person`.

And this code is no different from yours:

```
public class Data<E extends Person> {
    public void doSomething(List<E> data) {
        data.stream().reduce((a, b) -> (E)a.foo(b));
    }
}
```